# Extract Title+links from homepage

Tags: python, rss

im looking to make my own RSS with python

is it possible to extract just the Title and the downloadlinks("uploaded") from hdarea.org

heres a [code example](http://pastie.org/8495459)

and thats waht ive got so far

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://hd-area.org").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

for title in soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"}):
    print (title.getText())
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
  if 'Uploaded.net' in a:
    print a['href']
```

it already extracts the titles.

but im stuck where the links should be extracted.

it extracts but not in right order...

any suggestions how i could make sure that the script first gonna check if "title" and "link" is in this div class `"<div class="topbox">"`

**EDIT**

now im done

this is the final code

thanks guys - for pushing me in the right direction

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
import datetime
import PyRSS2Gen

print "top_rls"
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://hd-area.org/index.php?s=Cinedubs").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
movieTit = []
movieLink = []
for title in soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"}):
    movieTit.append(title.getText())

for span in soup.findAll('span', attrs={"style":"display:inline;"},recursive=True):
    for a in span.findAll('a'):            
        if 'ploaded' in a.getText():
            movieLink.append(a['href'])
        elif 'cloudzer' in a.getText():
            movieLink.append(a['href'])

for i in range(len(movieTit)):
    print movieTit[i]
    print movieLink[i]

rss = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(
    title = "HD-Area Cinedubs",
    link = "http://hd-area.org/index.php?s=Cinedubs",
    description = " "
                  " ",

    lastBuildDate = datetime.datetime.now(),
    items = [
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = movieTit[0],
         link = movieLink[0]),
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = movieTit[1],
         link = movieLink[1]),
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = movieTit[2],
         link = movieLink[2]),
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = movieTit[3],
         link = movieLink[3]),
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = movieTit[4],
         link = movieLink[4]),
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = movieTit[5],
         link = movieLink[5]),
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = movieTit[6],
         link = movieLink[6]),
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = movieTit[7],
         link = movieLink[7]),
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = movieTit[8],
         link = movieLink[8]),
       PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
         title = movieTit[9],
         link = movieLink[9]),
    ])

rss.write_xml(open("cinedubs.xml", "w"))
```

Comment: What do you mean: not in right order?

Comment: yep. i guess thats wha im trying to say with my bad english :)

Comment: Oh, I meant: what do you mean by not in right order?

Comment: when u visit hd-area.org
each movie has 2 downloadlinks. each entry i scrape should produce 1title+1downloadlink and so on ... alternating way. now it doesnt do that. first it scrapes all titles than all downloadlinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this then:

```
movieTit = []
movieLink = []

for title in soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "title"}):
    movieTit.append(title.getText())
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    if 'ploaded' in a.getText():
        movieLink.append(a['href'])

for i in range(0,len(movieTit)/2,2):
    print movieTit[i]
    print movieTit[i+1]
    print movieLink[i]
    print movieLink[i+1]
```

Comment: Given that you get 2 titles and 2 links per movie, I rewrote that for-loop

Comment: looks like its working... i dont know why but the first 2 links doesnt fit the movies.

is it possible to just start with the 3rd link on the 1st movie ?

Comment: got it. +2. easy as pi ;)

Comment: what i just saw.

sometimes they change the domain extension. how can i ignore that ?

uploaded*???

Comment: change the if to: if 'ploaded' in a.getText() This way you also skip that sometimes it can be capital U or not.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion if first find all the

```
<div class="topbox">
```

if in the page have more than one of this. You can use the find_all function or the the find using like this :

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

# in case you want to find all of them
for item in soup.find_all('div', _class='topbox'):
    # in this line you have to check where is the title : <span>, <a> or other
    # check if the tag exist or not
    if item.span is not None: 
       title = item.span.text

    # the same for this
    if item.a is not None:
        link = item.a['href']
```

I don't find the div you want in the page. If you need anymore please tell me exactly you want.